# Wider line in QGraphicScene on MainWindow::resizeEvent

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qt5, qmainwindow

In a window I've got a QGraphicScene. Inside this QGraphicScene I draw some lines (see the first picture).

[image]

My bug is that when I resize the window the code below is called to fit the scene in the view.

```
void GoBobMainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    goView->fitInView(goScene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

But I get this.

[image]

EDIT: I get this on all platforms (OS X, Windows, GNU/Linux)

How do fix this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777936/why-do-my-my-line-widths-looks-different-in-a-qgraphicsscene-with-the-same-qpen

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with :

```
goView->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
```